# Get current locale date format in a JSP page

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc, user-interface, jstl

I need to print in a label in a jsp page the date format in the current locale. 
For example, if the browser of the user has the locale en_US, I would like to print 'mm/dd/yyyy'; while if it is en_GB 'dd/mm/yy'. 
Can someone suggest the jsp or jstl code for getting that info?

**EDIT**
I dont need to print the date, I need to print exactly the string 'dd/mm/yyyy' or 'mm/dd/yyyy' according with the current locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use I18N and L18N in your JSP code :

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.Locale" %>
```

Get the `Locale` from the `request`:

```
 Locale locale = request.getLocale();
```

And apply the `DateFormat` based on `Locale`.

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
String formattedDate = df.format(yourDate);
```

To get the actual format for a `Locale` , you can try something like this :

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = (SimpleDateFormat) df;
String pattern = sf.toLocalizedPattern();
```

**Using JSTL's [formatDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) :**

> When you use JSTL format tag `<fmt:formatDate>` and `<fmt:formatNumber>`, JSTL automatically takes care of locale resolution. Depending on the browser’s locale setting JSTL will display the date and numbers.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" type="both" dateStyle="full" timeStyle="short" />
```

Comment: okay, but I want to know what the format is, because want to print in a label 'dd/mm/yyyy' or 'mm/dd/yyyy' according to the current locale

Comment: how can I achieve that result?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.Locale" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*,javax.servlet.http.* "%>
<%@ page import="java.text.DateFormat,java.util.Date" %>

<%
String title = "Locale Specific Dates";
//Get the client's Locale
Locale locale = request.getLocale( );
String date = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
                              DateFormat.FULL, 
                              DateFormat.SHORT, 
                              locale).format(new Date( ));
%>
<html>
<head>
<title><% out.print(title); %></title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1><% out.print(title); %></h1>
</center>
<div align="center">
<p>Local Date: <%  out.print(date); %></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" scope="session"/>
```

Or refer [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/update-jstl-locale/)

Answer (score -1):

Look at the `java.util.ResourceBundle` class, mainly the `getBundle()` method. (You can use this, or implement a similar mechanism. To get locale information you can use the following code...

```
Locale rLocale = request.getLocale();
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyLocale", rLocale);
Locale selectedLocale = bundle.getLocale();
```